# Pine Script indicator: show daily candle ONLY today

Tags: tradingview-api, indicator

I love that function, but I want it to show up ONLY on the actual day (and not everywhere on the chart).

Possible?

Thanks!

```
cdo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
cdc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
cdh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
cdl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)`

//Colour
opencolour = cdo != cdo[1] ? na : color.black
highcolour = cdh != cdh[1] ? na : color.black
lowcolour = cdl != cdl[1] ? na : color.black
closecolour = cdc != cdc[1] ? na : color.black

//Daily Plots
offs_daily = 0
openplot = plot(cdo, title='Current Open', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=opencolour)
closeplot = plot(cdc, title='Current Close', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=closecolour)
plot(cdh, title='Current High', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=highcolour)
plot(cdl, title='Current Low', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=lowcolour)
fill(openplot, closeplot, color=cdo < cdc ? color.green : color.red, editable=true, transp=85)`
```

I'm not a programmer. I only manage.

I found this example (about applying the code on the actual day only), but I just can't make it work into the previous code.

```
study("Today Open Yesterday Close", overlay=true)
tdo = security(tickerid, 'D', open) // today

isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true

plot(tdo,linewidth=1,color=isToday ? maroon : na)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way.
In fact, you must use the variable isToday in each plot function to plot only if isToday is true.
Try this code :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Today Open Yesterday Close", overlay=true)

isToday = false
if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true
isToday := true

cdo = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
cdc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)
cdh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
cdl = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

//Colour
opencolour = cdo != cdo[1] ? na : color.black
highcolour = cdh != cdh[1] ? na : color.black
lowcolour = cdl != cdl[1] ? na : color.black
closecolour = cdc != cdc[1] ? na : color.black

//Daily Plots
offs_daily = 0
openplot = plot(cdo, title='Current Open', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=isToday ? opencolour : na )
closeplot = plot(cdc, title='Current Close', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=isToday ? closecolour : na)
plot(cdh, title='Current High', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=isToday ? highcolour : na )
plot(cdl, title='Current Low', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, color=isToday ? lowcolour : na)
fill(openplot, closeplot, color=isToday ? cdo < cdc ? color.new(color.green,85) : color.new(color.red ,85): na, editable=true)
```

Be carreful, the version used in important. Your first code was in version 5 and the second part was in version 4. You can choose only one.